# jquery.base64の変数b10には、何の数値が格納されているのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery.base64の

```js
  function _encode( s ) {}
```

の中にb10という変数があるのですが、何の数値が格納されているのでしょうか。
ご教授をお願いします。

[jquery.base64ダウンロードサイト](https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base64](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)は8bit文字×3文字（＝24bit）を6bit文字×4文字で表現するエンコード形式です。
ですので引数sから3文字取り出してb10を作成し、

```
b10 = ( _getbyte( s, i ) << 16 ) | ( _getbyte( s, i + 1 ) << 8 ) | _getbyte( s, i + 2 );
```

b10から4文字出力しています。

```
x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 >> 18 ) );
x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 12 ) & 0x3F ) );
x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( ( b10 >> 6 ) & 0x3f ) );
x.push( _ALPHA.charAt( b10 & 0x3f ) );
```